# Separate Clicks, same Button, function then back to normal

Tags: javascript, button, font-awesome

I am able to click the button and have it change, but I want to be able to click it again and have it return back to normal, preferably using Vanilla JavaScript or JavaScript.

I have included my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code.
I looked at many forums, and most questions are about running multiple functions with one click; however, I want to be able to run separate functions one click after the other. Or is there a way to just have the second click automatically have it return to normal without writing a seperate function?

```js
function thermometer(){
  var a;

  a=document.getElementById('span1');
  a.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-thermometer-empty"></i>`;
  setTimeout(function () {
    a.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-thermometer-quarter"></i>`;
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function(){
    a.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-thermometer-half"></i>`;
  }, 2000)
  setTimeout(function(){
    a.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-thermometer-three-quarters"></i>`;
  }, 3000)
  setTimeout(function(){
    a.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-thermometer-full"></i>`;
  }, 4000)
}

thermometer();
setInterval(thermometer, 5000);

function myFunction(){
  b=document.getElementById('jo');
  b.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-meh-rolling-eyes"></i>`;
}
```

```css
#span1{
  font-size: 80px;
  color: hotpink;
  padding-left: 20px;
  }
#span1:hover {
  color:rgb(219, 33, 0);
  }
.todo-button{
  font-size: 38px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  color: white;
  background: lawngreen;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  }
.fa-grin-tongue:hover{
  color: yellow;
  }
h1{
  font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 45px;
  color:hotpink;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vp86vTRFVJgpjF9jiIGPEEqYqlDwgyBgEF109VFjmqGmIY/Y4HV4d3Gp2irVfcrp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1 id="h1t">Thermo-Listing<span id="span1"></span></h1>
        <form class="todo-input"></form>
<!--Button Information Below-->
        <button onclick="myFunction();" class="todo-button" type="submit" id="jo"><i class="fas fa-grin-tongue"></i></button>
    </header>
    <div class="todo-container">
        <ul class="todo-list">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e4dab53a8c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Usually you add the element and hide it. Then the click event handler checks if it's hidden and hides or reveals it accordingly.

Comment: Could you show me how that looks like? or a sample code of that? if you don't mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm introducing a `toggle` variable that increments with each click inside your function. Based on the modulus `% 2`, we can alternate the toggle to show your different emojis.

```js
let toggle = 0;
const rolling = '<i class="fas fa-meh-rolling-eyes"></i>';
const tongue = '<i class="fas fa-grin-tongue"></i>';

function thermometer(){
  var a;

  a=document.getElementById('span1');
  a.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-thermometer-empty"></i>`;
  setTimeout(function () {
    a.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-thermometer-quarter"></i>`;
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function(){
    a.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-thermometer-half"></i>`;
  }, 2000)
  setTimeout(function(){
    a.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-thermometer-three-quarters"></i>`;
  }, 3000)
  setTimeout(function(){
    a.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-thermometer-full"></i>`;
  }, 4000)
}

thermometer();
setInterval(thermometer, 5000);

function myFunction(){
  b=document.getElementById('jo');
  b.innerHTML = (++toggle % 2) ? rolling : tongue;
}
```

```css
#span1{
  font-size: 80px;
  color: hotpink;
  padding-left: 20px;
  }
#span1:hover {
  color:rgb(219, 33, 0);
  }
.todo-button{
  font-size: 38px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  color: white;
  background: lawngreen;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  }
.fa-grin-tongue:hover{
  color: yellow;
  }
h1{
  font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 45px;
  color:hotpink;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vp86vTRFVJgpjF9jiIGPEEqYqlDwgyBgEF109VFjmqGmIY/Y4HV4d3Gp2irVfcrp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1 id="h1t">Thermo-Listing<span id="span1"></span></h1>
        <form class="todo-input"></form>
<!--Button Information Below-->
        <button onclick="myFunction();" class="todo-button" type="submit" id="jo"><i class="fas fa-grin-tongue"></i></button>
    </header>
    <div class="todo-container">
        <ul class="todo-list">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e4dab53a8c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will study your code and more about incrementing and toggling.